# Set entire selected DataGrid row template to CellEditingTemplate

Tags: wpf, datagrid, selected, celltemplate, celleditingtemplate

I have a question regarding WPF DataGrid. For the sake of IDataErrorInfo validation I would like to set the entire selected row as editing - by that I mean setting every cell's (in that row) data template from CellTemplate to CellEditingTemplate.

This is one column for example:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Note">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>                                    
            <TextBox Name="textBoxNote" Text="{Binding Note, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />                                    
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Note}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Is that possible in XAML (triggers of some kind)? How would I do that in codebehind? I have found the solution with two separate styles as resources and then programamatically toggling between them in Row_Selected and Row_Unselected events, but I would rather use the existing above XAML code for columns (with separate CellTemplate and CellEditingTemplate).

Can anyone point me the right way?

Thanks in advance. Best regards,
DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I didn't manage to put the whole row into edit mode, but I managed to revalidate the IDataErrorInfo object - kind of forced IDataErrorInfo validation. This was the reason for me wanting to set edit mode on all cells of the row - to bind controls from CellEditingTemplate to object properties with ValidateOnDataErrors = True. Otherwise I added new object to the DataGrid, but properties (except of the edited ones) never got validated.

In the superclass of all of my model objects (that extends IDataErrorInfo) I added this method:

```
public virtual void Revalidate() // never needed to override though
{
    Type type = this.GetType();

    // "touch" all of the properties of the object - this calls the indexer that checks
    // if property is valid and sets the object's Error property 
    foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in type.GetProperties())
    {                
        var indexerProperty = this[propertyInfo.Name];
    }
}
```

Now when the user adds new object to DataGrid I manually call myNewObject.Revalidate() method to set the Error property which I check before saving the object to the database.

Thanks and regards,
DB